# open cv install not working properly

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

when i am doing make in **`/opencv/build`** directory it is working upto some extent after that it is showing this kind of error what should i do

> Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_core
>   CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_arithm.cpp.o: file not
>   recognized: 
>       File truncated collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status modules/core
>       /CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/build.make:824: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_core' failed make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_core]
>   Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1421: recipe for target
>   'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/all' failed make[1]: ***
>   [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely here:

> CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/test/ocl/test_arithm.cpp.o: file not recognized: File truncated

Delete the object (.o) file and rerun. The make call was probably interrupted before which caused the object file to be truncated.